# A condition for a function of the form $\langle x, F(x)\rangle$ to attain its minimum

Tags: proof-verification, optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Let $F : \mathbb{R^n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R^n}$ be a differentiable function, with positive definite Jacobian matrix. Prove that function $f(x) = \langle x, F(x) \rangle$, with assumptions $x \ge 0, F(x) \ge 0$ has minimum in point $x^*$ if and only if $\langle x^*, F(x^*)\rangle = 0$

I managed to prove the simpler implication:  if

$\langle x^*, F(x^*)\rangle = 0, x \ge 0,  F(x) \ge 0 \Rightarrow \langle x, F(x) \rangle \ge 0 = \langle x^*, F(x^*) \rangle,$ thus this part is proved, because $F$ is positive definite. How do I even start the other part? The book suggests to use the theorem of F. John. Thank you in advance.
$$Edit:$$
The solution book shows is:

If the problem has a solution $x^*$ then, by theorem of F. John, there exist a number $u_0$ and vectors $u^1, u^2$ for which: $$u_0 F(x^*) + u_0 \frac{\partial F}{\partial x}(x^*) - \frac{\partial F}{\partial x}(x^*) u^1 - u^2 = 0,
\langle u^1, F(x^*) \rangle = 0, \langle u^2, x \rangle = 0, (u_0, u^1, u^2) > 0. $$
{First, should it be $x^*$ where it states just $x$?}

Now, after multiplication of the first equation by vector $u_0 x - u^1$ we get:
$$\langle \frac{\partial F}{\partial x}(x^*)(u_0 x - u^1), u_0 x - u^1 \rangle + u_0^2 \langle F(x^*), x^* \rangle + \langle u^1, u^2 \rangle = 0. $$
{Secondly, how does one obtaim this after the scalar multiplication?}

All addends, by assumptions, are non-negative, so they all equal 0. Thus, $u_0^2 \langle F(x^*), x^* \rangle = 0.$
If $u_0 = 0$, then because of $\langle u^1, u^2 \rangle = 0$ and $u^1 \ge 0, u^2 \ge 0,$ we have $(u_0, u^1, u^2) = 0,$ which is impossible.
Hence, $u_0 \ne 0$, so $\langle x^*, F(x^*) \rangle = 0.$ This proves the first implication. The second implication is trivial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the behavior of $f(x+hx)$ as $h\to 0$: 
$$
f(x+hx) = \langle x + hx, F(x+hx)\rangle
= f(x) + h (\langle x, F(x)\rangle + \langle x, J_F(x)x\rangle) + o(h)
$$
where $J_F(x)$ is the Jacobian matrix of $F$ at $x$.

Suppose $x^*$ is a point of minimum. Whether it is interior or boundary point of the domain, $x^*+hx^*$ belongs to the domain for $h>0$. Therefore, the coefficient of $h$ in the above expansion must be $\le 0$. 
On the other hand, 
$$\langle x^*, J_F(x^*)x^*\rangle \ge 0$$
(note that being positive *semi*definite is enough here). Hence $\langle x^*, F(x^*)\rangle \le 0$. But as you noted, $\langle x^*, F(x^*)\rangle \ge 0$ always holds. Thus $\langle x^*, F(x^*)\rangle = 0$.

Comment: Thank you. I do understand the proof, but this is a problem from Mathematical programming course I have this semester, and assistent gave us the problem, among others. He requires F. John theorem in solution and he even gave us the solution with intersteps, but it doesn't look like the theorem. Is it fine if I post the solution, and ask for proof verification? This solution is intuitive and comprehensive, but is not one that is required. Thank you, anyway.

Comment: Someone may be able to use F. John's theorems if your question includes a statement of it. F. John proved more than one theorem.

Comment: I will add in queation statement what the book advises in intersteps. However there are several points where it confuses me, so I will add proof verification tag. Is that fine? Thank you for you help.